# MySQL group by DAY not showing results of current month

Tags: mysql, group-by

As the query states, it retrieves records from june to august, but why is the results only display until july 31st?, i have records from 2014-06-08 to 2014-08-07. Does it have a problem since the current month as of today is august?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS, DATE(created)
FROM battle
WHERE player_id = 1234 AND enemy_id = 4567
AND created BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DAY(created)
ORDER BY created ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're grouping by `DAY(created)`, which is just the day of the month. So it's combining June 1, July 1, and August 1 into the same group, June 2, July 2, and August 2 into the next group, and so on.

Use `GROUP BY DATE(created)` to include the month in the grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query as follows

Use `GROUP BY DATE(created)` instead of `GROUP BY DAY(created)`

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS, DATE(created)
    FROM battle
    WHERE player_id = 1234 AND enemy_id = 4567
    AND created BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY DATE(created)
    ORDER BY created ASC;
```

Comment: Oh, so day is the problem, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS, DATE
FROM battle
WHERE player_id = 1234 AND enemy_id = 4567
AND Date BETWEEN '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date ASC;
```